# using PHP file instead of EJS templating

Tags: php, ejs

I am trying to use add.php instead to add.ejs(templating) in my node express rest api modules. I have tried using 'php-node-npm' but after starting the server getting the following error:

```
var render = require('../view/index.js')({bin:"c://php//"});
                                        ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

I am new to this, so unable to figure it out. Here's my code and directory structure of my files:

[image: dir]

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

const app = express();

// Middleware
var render = require('../view/index.js')({bin:"c://php//"});

render(__dirname+'./add.php', {}, function(e, r) {
    console.log(r);
})

// use PHP as view engine in Express
var phpnode = require('../view/index.js')({bin:"c:\\php\\php.exe"});

router.set('view', __dirname);
router.engine('php', phpnode);
router.set('view engine', 'php');


// Mongo URI


// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

// @route GET /
// @desc Loads form
router.all('./add.php', function(req, res) {
  res.render('add');
})


// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file to DB
router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  // res.json({ file: req.file });
  res.redirect('/');
});

// @route GET /files
// @desc  Display all files in JSON
router.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No files exist'
      });
    }

    // Files exist
    return res.json(files);
  });
});

// @route GET /files/:filename
// @desc  Display single file object
router.get('/files/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      });
    }
    // File exists
    return res.json(file);
  });
});

// @route GET /image/:filename
// @desc Display Image
router.get('/image/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      });
    }

    // Check if image
    if (file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png') {
      // Read output to browser
      const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
      readstream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        err: 'Not an image'
      });
    }
  });
});

// @route DELETE /files/:id
// @desc  Delete file
router.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {
  gfs.remove({ _id: req.params.id, root: 'uploads' }, (err, gridStore) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({ err: err });
    }

    res.redirect('/');
  });
});


const Product = require("../models/product");

router.post("/", upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
  const product = new Product({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    price: req.body.price,
    productImage: req.file,
    reference: req.body.reference,
    description: req.body.description,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    date: req.body.date,
    category: req.body.category,
    newProduct: req.body.newProduct,
    relatedProduct: req.body.relatedProduct
  });
  product
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Created product successfully",
        createdProduct: {
            name: result.name,
            price: result.price,
            _id: result._id,
            request: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: "http://localhost:3000/products/" + result._id
            }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var render = require('../view/index.js')({bin:"c://php//"});
> ```

You are taking whatever `../view/index.js` exports and trying to call it as a function.

It isn't a function.

You need to either:

- Change `../view/index.js` so it exports a function *or*
- Change what you do with whatever it is that it exports